# How is the correct way to call read function of file operations?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

in the struct file_operations, which is defined in the line 1517 from:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fs.h?a=arm

There is method in the line 1520 to read operations:

```
  ssize_t (* read) (struct file *, char __ user *, size_t, loff_t *);
```

which is the correct way to call this method from the application?
  I'm having trouble passing as a parameter the `"loff_t *"`

Comment: `loff_t outoff; ssize_t readb = read(fp, buf, how_many, &outoff);`

Comment: thanks, but I print the value from the driver and comes as 0


printk(KERN_ALERT "Offset: %lld\n", *offset);

the result in "dmesg" its always 0

Answer (score 1):

To get non-zero value in "loff_t *" parameter with a very first read from your application you need to call 'lseek' first, i believe.

like:

```
#include <unistd.h>
...
offset = ...
pos = lseek(fh, (off_t) offset, SEEK_SET);
read(fh, buffer, bytesToRead);
```

Here is offset will be passed to kernel via 'loff_t* parameter'.